# How to use subcaption with standalone

Tags: subcaption, standalone

I tried to `\input` in my main document file a `standalone` section, which uses the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package. The `standalone` file compiles just fine. But when I try to compile the main document I get an

```
Undefined control sequence
```

error in `caption3.sty`.

The error is caused by the `\usepackage{subcaption}` alone, so it even occurs when `subcaption` is not actually used.

Here is a minimal working example:

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \input{subcaption_with_standalone}
\end{document}
```

`subcaption_with_standalone.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
  This does not even use a subfigure.
\end{document}
```

How can I make `subcaption` (or something similar, preferrably not deprecated) work with standalone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several packages use the `\AtBeginDocument` command. When these packages are loaded in the preamble of a sub-file, these commands will never be executed.

The option `subpreamples=true` is thought for macros and alike, not for loading packages. If you need the package in your sub-file, you have to load it in your main file as well. Alternatively, you may just compile your sub-file with all packages you need and run the main file without the option `subpreambles=true`.

Loading `subcaption` in the main preamble works:

**main.tex**

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \input{subcaption_with_standalone}
\end{document}
```

**subcaption_with_standalone.tex**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{2in}
    \centering
    \missingfigure{Figure 1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{2in}
    \centering
    \missingfigure{Figure 2}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to absorb the comments inside answer instead of making a pointer from answer to outside ?

Comment: Of course. Are my assumptions more ore less correct? I will insert, you may edit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have been successfully abusing the subpreambles option for quite some time :-)